# Parse DateTime with $1 and $2 value from regex

Tags: regex, perl, datetime

I'm trying to delete some **.log** Files with perl.
I have three different variants of filenames.

`1: stdout.log.190605113009-190605115714`
`2: stdout.log.190605110200-190605113009.gz_2019-06-07` and
`3: stdout.log.unknown-190618025803.gz_2019-06-19`

Now with my regex I'm splitting the name so that I get two groups with the date.

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;


use local::lib;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Basename;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Duration;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_WEEK';

#How to use dry Flag in cmd:
#prove --dry C:/path/to/file/file.pl [start argument]

#Get the script parameter
my $path = $ARGV[0];
my $file;
my $filename;

#Looks if script parameter != null
if (not defined $path) {
    die "Need a path\n"
}

#Looks if $path is a existing directory
if (-d $path) {
    print "Directory exist\n";

    DoDir($path);
} else {
    die "Directory don't exist";
}

#Goes recursively through the directory
#and looks for other directories and .log files.
sub DoDir {

    my $dir = shift;

    opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Unable to open $dir: $!";
    my(@files) = grep {!/^\.\.?$/ } readdir(DIR);
    closedir(DIR);

    foreach (@files) {
        #Looks for child directories.
        if (-d ($file = "$dir\\$_")) {
            print "Found a directory: $file\n";
            DoDir($file);
        } else {

            checkDate($file);
        }
    }
}

sub checkDate {

    $filename = basename($file);

    if ($filename =~ m/^\D?20\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_[\w_]+.log$/) {

        NormalFile();


    }
    elsif($filename =~ m/^wl-deploy-\d+_[\w\-_.]+\d+\.log$/) {

        DeployFile();
    }
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^\D?20(\d{2}_){3}[\w_]+\.log\.gz_\D?20(\d{2}-){2}\d{2}$/) {

        #print "$filename: File match .log.gz\n";
    }
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^stdout\.log(\.\w+?-\w+?(\.gz_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)?$/) {

        StdoutFile();
        #print "$filename: File match stdout\n";
    }
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^\D?20\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\.[\w\-]+\.error$/) {

        ErrorFile();
    }
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^[\w]{2}\_[\w]+\.log\.lck$/) {

        LckFile();
    }
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^server\.log(\d{5})?$/) {

        #print "$filename: File Match server\n";
    }
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^access\.log(\d{5})?$/) {

        #print "$filename: File match access\n";
    }
    else{

        print "$filename: don't match\n";
    }

}

sub NormalFile() {

    my $chars = substr($filename, 0 , 10);
    #Check if extension is equals .log

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($chars);


    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract ( weeks => 2);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        #print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        #print "delete\n";
    }
}

sub DeployFile() {

    $filename =~ s/[^\d]//g;
    my $dateFromString = substr($filename, 0 , 6);

    my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $dateFromString);
    $year = "20".$year;

    my $dateFromFile = $year."_".$month."_".$day;

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($dateFromFile);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract ( weeks => 2);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        #print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        #print "delete\n";
    }
}

sub LckFile {

    #print "$file delete\n";
}

sub ErrorFile {

    $filename = substr($filename, 0 , 10);
    $filename =~ s/-/_/g;

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($filename);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract ( weeks => 2);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        #print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        #print "delete\n";
    }
}

sub StdoutFile {

    print "$filename\n";
    $filename =~ /^stdout\.log\.((?:\d+?)|unknown)-(\d+?)(?:\.gz_\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})?$/g;

    if ($1 ne "unknown") {

        my $firstDate = substr($1, 0, 6);
        my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $firstDate);
        $year = "20" . $year;
        $firstDate = $year . "_" . $month . "_" . $day;
        print "$firstDate\n";
    }

    my $secondDate = substr($2, 0, 6);
    my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $secondDate);
    $year = "20" . $year;
    $secondDate = $year . "_" . $month . "_" . $day;
    print "$secondDate\n";

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($secondDate);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract ( weeks => 2);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        print "delete\n";
    }
}
```

**Error Message**
Use of uninitialized value $1 in string ne at line 224.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in substr at line 226.
Use of uninitialized value $year in concatenation (.) or string at line 228.
Use of uninitialized value $month in concatenation (.) or string at line 229.
Use of uninitialized value $day in concatenation (.) or string at line 229.
20__
Use of uninitialized value $2 in substr at line 233.
Use of uninitialized value $year in concatenation (.) or string at line 235.
Use of uninitialized value $month in concatenation (.) or string at line 236.
Use of uninitialized value $day in concatenation (.) or string at line 236.
20__
Your datetime does not match your pattern. at line 245.

Comment: Did you missed `.log` in the regex at the end? Because you are matching the log file. But your pattern ends with to match the digit.

Comment: @mkHun These are zip files filled with .log files. But that is not my problem. The problem is that I can't convert the value from the regex to a DateTime

Comment: The only use of `ne` in your code is on line 205. Your error message says it is on line 224. There is an unexplained discrepancy of 19 lines. But if you take account of that discrepancy then the rest of the errors seem to match up with your code. But really, not everyone is going to take the time to investigate that discrepancy. You need to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The full code**

It's not though, is it? I needed to add a bit more in order to test your code. Here's what I ended up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Added these three essential lines
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

# Added sample log file names
my @logs = (qw[
  stdout.log.190605113009-190605115714
  stdout.log.190605110200-190605113009.gz_2019-06-07
  stdout.log.unknown-190618025803.gz_2019-06-19
]);

# Added call to subroutine
StdoutFile($_) for @logs;

sub StdoutFile {
    # Added parameter handling
    my $filename = shift;

    print "$filename\n";
    $filename =~ /^stdout\.log\.((?:\d+?)|unknown)-(\d+?)(?:\.gz_\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})?$/g;

    if ($1 ne "unknown") {

        my $firstDate = substr($1, 0, 6);
        my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $firstDate);
        $year = "20" . $year;
        $firstDate = $year . "_" . $month . "_" . $day;
        print "$firstDate\n";
    }

    my $secondDate = substr($2, 0, 6);
    my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $secondDate);
    $year = "20" . $year;
    $secondDate = $year . "_" . $month . "_" . $day;
    print "$secondDate\n";

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($secondDate);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract ( weeks => 2);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        print "delete\n";
    }
# Added missing closing brace
}
```

And when I run it, I get the following output:

```
stdout.log.190605113009-190605115714
2019_06_05
2019_06_05
delete
stdout.log.190605110200-190605113009.gz_2019-06-07
2019_06_05
2019_06_05
delete
stdout.log.unknown-190618025803.gz_2019-06-19
2019_06_18
delete
```

And no errors.

So presumably, the additions I've made (all of which are marked with comments) don't match the code that I haven't seen.

If you give us a program that we can run and that demonstrates the error, then we can probably help you fix it. If we have to guess at some of your code, then we'll be less useful.

**Update:** Looking at your error messages, it seems very likely that you have some log file names that don't match your regex. The best way to deal with that is probably to present a warning and to return immediately from the subroutine in these circumstances.

After the regex check, you could add something like this:

```
unless (defined $1 and defined $2) {
  warn "Log file '$filename' does not match regex\n";
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry the program is a lot bigger so I only posted the sub routine. I'll edit my post

Comment: @poisn: Ok, you've made the heading more accurate. But that's not really very helpful, is it? I'm still guessing at parts of your program. And those parts are apparently the bits that are causing your problems.

Comment: Yeah the problem is still here. I'll update the code again

Comment: @poisn: *I'll update the code again* Again? You've haven't updated the code yet :-) And also, the error messages you quote should contain line numbers (but you've removed them). It would be helpful to know which lines of your code match those line numbers.